# Changing page numbering does only work for two arabic numbered pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using the code below to change the style of my page numbering. 
This works quite well. But only for the first two arabic numbered pages. 
That means page 1 and page 2 are showed correctly. all other pages are missing the blue line as you can see in the pictures.

ToC and ToT and ToP are numbered roman and there the code works without problems.

Any ideas? thanks

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }%\tgherosfont%
        {\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        %\tgherosfont%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the style for all pages and not only for `plain`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{chaptercolor}{blue}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        {\ }%\tgherosfont%
        {\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
        \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }
    \fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        %\tgherosfont%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
            \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfootoffset[OR]{1.85cm}
\fancyfoot[OR]{%
    {\ }%\tgherosfont%
    {\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
    \hspace*{10pt}\begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
        \color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\fancyfootoffset[EL]{1.85cm}
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
    %\tgherosfont%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1.5cm}%
        \raggedleft\color{chaptercolor}\normalsize\textbf{\thepage}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{10pt}{\color{chaptercolor}\rule[-90pt]{0.8mm}{100pt}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image]

(instead of creating this layout yourself, you could also use the `cleanthesis` package which has such page number per default)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much! Is there a way to compoine, "fancy and plain" in one "command"? something like that: \pagestyle{fancy, plain}

Comment: @C.Hediger I don't know if they can be combined

Comment: ok, no problem :) thanks anyway